# Can I copy id_dsa keys?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix

I generated id_dsa key (ssh key) for my client, and then copied them over to authorized_keys.

And it works.

Is it possible to copy these Keys to another user account, so I don't have to re-create these keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

short answer is yes. there's nothing about these keys that are special. just copy the files to the proper location and set the permissions (user:group and ugo) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Longer answer is "think really hard about whether you want to do it." If one user gets compromised, you'll need to provide keys for all of them. Further, if the users know they are sharing keys, they will be able to impersonate each other.